# Streamlit button on_click not refreshing images from API Endpoint URL

Tags: image, streamlit, get-request

I am new to Streamlit, and am trying to build a simple app which will show a cat picture from https://cataas.com/cat on clicking a button. I have the following simple code:

```
def show_kitty():
    st.image('https://cataas.com/cat')

st.button("Click for cats", on_click = show_kitty())
```

However, the app renders a picture on the first button click, and the picture does not change on subsequent clicks.

I tried doing the same with texts instead of images, this time displaying cat facts:

```
def get_cat_fact():
    x = requests.get('https://catfact.ninja/fact')
    st.text(x.text)

st.button("Click for cat facts", on_click = get_cat_fact())
```

and it worked - the text changes on every button click.

Does anyone know why this might be? How can I make Streamlit refresh images too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `st.image()` is caching the result, meaning that whenever you call it with the same input parameter, it will simply take the same result as before.

You should simply make it explicit:

```py
import requests

def show_kitty():
    image = requests.get("https://cataas.com/cat").content
    st.image(image)

st.button("Click for cats", on_click=show_kitty)
```

Comment: I figured st.image() was caching the result, but I did not know how to prevent it. This worked perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the correct implementation is:

```py
import requests

def show_kitty():
    image = requests.get("https://cataas.com/cat").content
    st.image(image)

if st.button("Click for cats"):
    show_kitty()
```

You must consider the sparse code like the main specification of UI, and into the callback if you need you can change the state of global variable ([example here](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/session-state#example-2-session-state-and-callbacks)) without changing directly the elements of UI. I think that is the best practice.